# \urlstyle{same} with apacite

Tags: bibliographies, urls, apa-style

I use `apacite` to create a bibliography according to APA guidelines for my article. Some of the references contain URLs. By default, LaTeX shows these in a different, monospace font than the rest of the article. I dislike this, so wish to use the `url` package with `\urlstyle{same}`. This does not work however in combination with `apacite`.

Here is a little reference document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
\url{http://www.google.com}
\end{document}
```

Leaving out the `apacite` package will render the link in the document font. It will currently render in the monospace font however. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this, so I can have APA references and good looking URLs?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`apacite` uses `\AtBeginDocument` to switch to the `APACtt` URL style, but one may also switch to `APACsame`. See section 8.2 of the `apacite` manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}

\begin{document}
\url{http://www.google.com}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get how it exactly works, but that does the trick indeed. Thanks for the help and warm welcome!