# Problems with website formatting in apacite's reference page

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

This is a very specific problem, but it's driving me crazy.  I'd like my output to look like this:

Author, A. A., & Author, B. B. (Date of publication). Title of article. Title of Journal, volume number, page range. Retrieved from http://www.someaddress.com/full/url/

With the url the same font as the reference and without a period at the end of the reference.

My problem is that I'm getting either the url in a different font or a period at the end of the reference.

My `bib` file looks something like this:

```
@article{ rospa,
  year = {n.d.},
  title = {Seat Belts: A short history},
  journal = {The Royal Society for the Prevention of Accidents},
  howpublished = {Retrieved March 7, 2014, from
    http://www.rospa.com/roadsafety/adviceandinformation/vehiclesafety/
    in-carsafetycrash-worthiness/seat-belt-history.aspx}
}

@article{ ehow,
  author = {Sefcik, Lisa},
  title = {Seat belt law history},
  journal = {eHow},
  url = {http://www.ehow.com/facts\_5008257\_seat-belt-law-history.html},
  urldate = {March 7, 2014},
  year = {n.d,}
}
```

And my `tex` file looks something like this:

```
\documentclass[man, apacite]{apa6}
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}
\author{weirdesky}
\title{test}
\shorttitle{test}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \cite{rospa}
  \cite{ehow}
  \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

And I get the rospa citation with a period at the end and the ehow citation with the url in a weird font.

I looked around and found [\urlstyle{same} with apacite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115517/urlstylesame-with-apacite) , and tried using the solution (although I don't know what it really does), but it didn't work.  Is there a way around this, or am I going to have to use the literal section?

I tried using \bibnodot{.}, but I get an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: PS Have you considered `biblatex`?

Comment: No?  To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what biblatex is.  Just that it's the thing that's making my `bbl` file (I think).

Comment: You're using `bibtex`. `biblatex` (ideally with `biber`) offers much more flexible handling of bibliographies and it is a lot easier to tweak the formatting. If it is an option (i.e. you don't have to conform to a requirement to use `bibtex`) it is worth looking into. It can use existing `.bib` files so initially it is pretty easy to dabble until you need to do something like this and then it makes life a lot easier.

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: URLs in roman without full-stops]

```
\documentclass[man,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{ rospa,
      year = {n.d.},
      title = {Seat Belts: A short history},
      journal = {The Royal Society for the Prevention of Accidents},
      url = {http://www.rospa.com/roadsafety/adviceandinformation/vehiclesafety/
        in-carsafetycrash-worthiness/seat-belt-history.aspx}
    }

    @article{ ehow,
      author = {Sefcik, Lisa},
      title = {Seat belt law history},
      journal = {eHow},
      url = {http://www.ehow.com/facts\_5008257\_seat-belt-law-history.html},
      urldate = {March 7, 2014},
      year = {n.d,}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\author{weirdesky}
\title{test}
\shorttitle{test}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \cite{rospa}
  \cite{ehow}
  \urlstyle{rm}% modify as appropriate
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I needed.  I was placing my \urlstyle{} tag in the preamble.  Thank you.  Thank you thank you thank you.  It now works perfectly.
I'd vote this answer up, but I can't.

Comment: @weirdesky You accepted it though ;). Note that I also loaded `url`. Perhaps this isn't necessary if `apa6` duplicates the functionality but the code seems to do different things depending on what's available (but I didn't look too deeply).

Comment: I didn't load `url`, but if it gives me trouble, I'll give that a shot.  Now I just have to work on removing that line between the title and my name on the title page.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `\bibnodot{.}` you need to have `\usepackage{apacdoc}` in your preamble.  E.g. for titles that end with punctuation, it [does what's required](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/07/punctuating-the-reference-list-entry.html).  Although note that titles that end with question marks seem to be processed just fine without this special treatment.

In LaTeX:

```
\usepackage{apacite}            % APA style citations
\usepackage{apacdoc}
```

In BibTeX:

```
@book{gabriel2002writer,
  Author = {Gabriel, Richard P},
  Publisher = {Addison-Wesley Longman Publishing Co., Inc.},
  Title = {{W}riter's {W}orkshops and the {W}ork of {M}aking {T}hings: {P}atterns, {P}oetry$\ldots$\bibnodot{.}},
  Year = {2002}}
```